# Unable to create Stripe Connected Account

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments, account

I have a Stripe Account for my Mobile Application and i what to create an a connected Account for test as it is the Seller's account.
The Seller is a user that shares a service or products' on our Marketplace but i face this error on Stripe dashboard:[Stripe Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKFuF.png) 
**Due to regulations in France, you can only create connected accounts using Stripe-hosted onboarding.**

I am trying to create a Connected Account for Testing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which type of Stripe accounts you're trying to create there are several steps to follow. First try to choose between the different types by reading this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts). Then depending on the type you chose you can follow one of the following guides:

- For Standard: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts
- For Express: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts
- For Custom: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts

Comment: I am trying to create an Express Account but i am facing this following error: StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot create new accounts because your account has been rejected.
    at Function.generate (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Error.js:10:20)
    at res.toJSON.then.Error_js_1.StripeAPIError.message (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/stripe/cjs/RequestSender.js:105:54)

Comment: This suggests your account has been flagged as fraudulent by Stripe for some reason - Not an issue we can help with here, you should contact  Stripe support

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has two ways to onboard connected accounts of each type:

- Standard / Express have Account Links and Oauth.
- Custom have Account Links and custom onboarding.

If your Platform is FR, then you cannot create Custom accounts using Account Links. You have to use custom onboarding using Account Tokens:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens

If you try to create a Custom account using Account Links, you should get this error:
`Connect platforms based in FR must create Custom accounts via account tokens. For documentation on account tokens, see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens`

That said, if you're creating Standard / Express accounts, you're not limited.